# Sync SQLite data from Android phone to Windows PC MySql Database

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization, data-synchronization

I am working on an application which requires synchronization of SQLite data from an Android device to MySQL database on desktop Windows PC I have no idea how to do this.

Please give me some reference of example codes or tutorials. I am searching on the internet but did not find tutorials or source code.

Comment: Take a look at the SQLite Backup API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a web service on server side (in any language, such as PHP, Java or .Net) then use `HttpUrlConnection` in your Android app (you can google how to connect or send data to web service).